# Как сделать, чтобы читая из файла python переводил коды символов в сами символы?

Tags: python, unicode, print

Когда строку с кодами типа `/uXXXX` я помещаю в переменную, то `print` замечательно их переводит в нужные символы.

```
jap = '\u7fa9\u5149 \u5317\u91ce\u8c37'
print(jap)
```

> 義光 北野谷

А когда я читаю эти же символы из файла и делаю `print`, то питон их не переводит, а оставляет как есть.

```
with open('jap.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

> \u7fa9\u5149 \u5317\u91ce\u8c37

Как сделать, чтобы читая из файла `python` переводил коды символов в сами символы?

Comment: Покажите что у вас в файле.

Comment: А вы пробовали их записать в файл и потом сравнить файл, из которого вы читаете и файл, который вы записали? Наверняка там разная кодировка просто. Нужно при чтении файла указывать кодировку, если это не `utf-8`.

Comment: А, стоп, может у вас в файле прямо вот так `\u7fa9\u5149 \u5317\u91ce\u8c37` текстом написано? А там не `json` какой в файле случайно? Если `json`, то и читайте его как `json` с помощью библиотеки `json` и всё само расшифруется.

Comment: >А, стоп, может у вас в файле прямо вот так \u7fa9\u5149 \u5317\u91ce\u8c37 текстом написано?

Да, именно так и записано, просто текстом.

Comment: Я принудительно пересохранил свой файл в кодировке utf-8, но это не повлияло на результат.
Меня больше всего раздражает, что если записать все в переменную x, а затем сделать print(x), то пайтон все покажет как следует. А из файла читает буквально, без преобразований.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, в файле для упрощения я оставил только одну строку.
`\u7fa9\u5149 \u5317\u91ce\u8c37`. Это plaint text document. Кодировка UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем файле обычные символы ASCII. Да, они являются последовательностями кодирующими юникод, но раскодировать их нужно вручную. В исходном файле питон, в строковых литералах интерпертатор это делает за вас.

```
with open('jap.txt', 'rb') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.decode("unicode_escape"))
```

Обратите внимание на флаг `b` в `open`.

Comment: Результат я предполагаю будет тот же. У меня подозрения что файл хранит именно как строку вот это значение: `\u7fa9\u5149 \u5317\u91ce\u8c37`. Мысль, что нужно обрабатывать строку, а не играться с unicode. ТС?

Comment: @Dmitry не знаю зачем я приплел в исходный вариант нормализацию. Тестировал в консоли, а там же интерпретатор сам декодирует экранирование. Вот этот вариант проверено рабочий.

Comment: вроде должен  в таком виде нормально обработать. Согласен

Comment: Вот так работает! Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```py
.........
        print(line.encode().decode("utf-8", "strict"))
```

первая директива `line.encode()` даст результат в битовой последовательности, примерно такой:

```py
b'\xe7\xbe\xa9\xe5\x85\x89 \xe5\x8c\x97\xe9\x87\x8e\xe8\xb0\xb7'
```

затем декодировать через utf-8. И результат, ожидаемо

```py
'義光 北野谷'
```

Comment: Дмитрий, не получилось, как вы предложили.
encode действительно закодировал в 

```b'\xe7\xbe\xa9\xe5\x85\x89 \xe5\x8c\x97\xe9\x87\x8e\xe8\xb0\xb7'```

А  decode вернул в изначальное состояние, т.е. в 

```\u7fa9\u5149 \u5317\u91ce\u8c37```